# Socrata nodejs - convert floating time stamp to a date time format

Tags: node.js, datetime, socrata

I am fetching data from an api using socrata : [Api Link](https://data.seattle.gov/resource/fire-911.json?$order=:created_at%20DESC)

There is a field called datetime which is of type [floating time stamp](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/floating_timestamp.html#,). How can I convert this value to datetime format. When I tried with normal time stamp to datetime format conversion, its always gives value similar to this: 1970-01-18T17:38:45.960Z. ie year is always: 1970.

Egs: datetime value: 1532325960

```
var d = new Date(1532325960);
console.log(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Is this correct or wrong?

Comment: The values you get from the API really looks like a seconds-based timestamp. JavaScript `Date` constructor uses milliseconds timestamp.

Comment: Thank you. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass timestamp value in milli seconds to the `Date` constructor. This will give you the correct date.

```
var d = new Date(1532325960 * 1000);
console.log(d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```